# unnecessary re-render reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

so i have this button to add an item to store
u cant add more than one
but when i click on the button twice or more it keep re-render two components twice
i tried to use useMemo to memorize the value but it wont work and get the (target) from e.target is undefined

```
const handleAdd = useMemo((e) => { 
  let newItem = {id : e.target.name, price: e.target.value, title: e.target.title, contity: 1} 
  item.push(newItem)
  const unique = Array.from(new Set(item.map(i => i.id))).map(id =>{return item.find(i => i.id === id)})
  setItem(unique)
}),[item])
```

any solution for useMemo or any other idea to avoid this unnecessary render ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done without any of these fancy hooks. Here is a great article about when to use `useMemo` or `useCallback` and why we don't need those most of the time: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback

Your code could simply check if the item already exists in the array before trying to update it:

```js
const handleAdd = (e) => { 
  const newId = e.target.name
  const itemFound = item.find((i) => i.id === newId)

  if (!itemFound) {
    const newItem = {id : e.target.name, price: e.target.value, title: e.target.title, contity: 1} 
    // Using spread to avoid mutability
    const updatedItem = [...item, newItem]
    setItem(updatedItem)
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm really glad you posted that article, because I wanted to say basically the same thing but had nothing to back it up. Saving an extra render (especially when only initiated on an event) is hardly worth any kind of refactor. Those two hooks get way over used and for such bad reasons.

Answer (score 1):

- to handle event's from buttons, inputs etc - use `useCallback` hook.
- you trigger setItem inside your hook and it causes re-render. Add condition inside your hook and trigger `setItem` only when id needed.